# Manipulating data in ms-access

Tags: ms-access

This may seem like an obvious question for those that use relational databases frequently, however, I'm only just getting started with them - in my case, ms-Access.

What I was wondering was when people talk about 'data manipulation' they frequently mean amended errors, cleaning up data in some form or another and generally updating a database in someway. I have a long history with using excel, and as such it feels quite intuitive for me to do things using this software. However, when you start incorporating a data management system like Access does one tend to manipulate data directly in Access- or for example, does one export data to excel, do what is required to the data and then export it back into the data base (this with my limited knowledge of Access seems like the obvious choice).

Thanks for the advice - furthermore if anyone has any good recommendations to up my 'Access game' quickly (possibly tutorials) that would be amazing.

Comment: Data within databases like Access is manipulated using SQL Queries, either hand written or created using the tools built into the application:  [Introduction to Access SQL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e)  (Other applications can also use SQL to access the data within the database).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I appreciate the response - as well as the link. Ok, so Excel is purely used for the analysis stages, right? All manipulation will be done directly to the database and then whatever data is required for analysis is extracted.

Comment: (In general) A database is the backend, its a read/write/edit storage repository with the ability to search for and return data based on criteria stated in a query (top beer sales for jan 1974 in Copenhagen sorted by brewers shoe size) other software is responsible for issuing these queries and doing something meaningful with the results.  Access is "special" because it has a lot of these tools built into it - Forms, Reports, Macros etc.

Comment: Any self-respecting database guy will want to rip your eyeballs out for equating Excel with "Database".  That being said, Access is generally a "beginner" database and so many people do just what you're describing; export data, "massage" it and then import it back into Access.  Once you become more familiar with Access, you'll discover that it's just as easy (and faster) to do all your data massaging in Access.  Until then, use whatever tool makes you most comfortable but don't get too reliant on taking the easy way out.

Comment: haha, thanks Johnny. I appreciate that Excel isn't a spreadsheet. Only that the 'visual' queues result in someone who isn't very experienced with Access thinking of the two as similar (i.e a huge array). However, I also realise that data-bases are far more robust when it comes to data handling. I'm hoping I will soon be one of those 'database guys', It's just that it can be a little overwhelming at first - do you have any suggestions for the best way to transition?

Comment: I can also imagine that the import/export route can be very cumbersome for large data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been through the same path you're taking now, and have had the same question before. It seemed like a struggle to relearn how to do a simple task in Excel using only Access. However, Access (or any SQL-based Management Studio) gives you a more robust system to work with.

For example, if you're cleaning data in Excel using VLOOKUPs to insert the proper values from a separate worksheet, it can be easy to write the equation but leaves you vulnerable to copying bad data (one row is an integer value instead of a string). With Access, there are better controls over the manipulation of data that will throw errors when it runs into unexpected values like that.

Furthermore, Access (or SQL in general) is much better at blending multiple datasets, validating data, and maintaining data integrity. Excel can do most of these tasks, but the processes are much more labor intensive.

Having said all of that, there are still situations where I might dump the results of a query into excel to verify calculations were done appropriately, sorting and filtering can sometimes be faster, and quick analyses can be easier to do in Excel, but that could be a function of my inexperience.

The steps I took in developing my Access knowledge was stepping back and learning about database design. I think that's the largest gap between Excel and Access: the relational model. After understanding the basics of relational databases, I suggest learning some SQL. I decided to step back again and learn T-SQL (slightly different syntax than the variation Access uses: Access-SQL, but is more mobile). If you can learn to write good queries with Access's GUI first, it makes it easier to apply SQL knowledge by transferring the GUI understanding to the outputted SQL code in Access.

Access is also far better with front-end development than Excel. Once you understand how the back-end works, the front-end is much easier to pick up. From there, you may consider learning some VBA to achieve more advanced solutions. Luckily, VBA also applies to Excel, so by that time you should be proficient at swapping back and forth between platforms, depending on the project.

For me, I used "SQL Queries For Mere Mortals" as my guide/tutorial for tackling database design and SQL understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much for that response. It covered pretty much everything I wanted to know. I will look into purchasing that book, as I tend to find it easier to learn when it's structured. I suspected this might be the case; trying to do things in excel and then importing back was down to mere inexperience rather than the correct way to carry out the task. The VLOOKUP example was pretty much exactly what I was thinking of. Looks like I need to crack on with learning something new... thanks again.